# OBD2Kit Swift example can't typecast, keep getting nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, obd-ii

Since there was no example code for using OBD2Kit and Swift I forked it into https://github.com/YannisDC/OBD2Kit and used it as a pod.

I translated some OBJ-C example code but can't seem to downcast the FLWiFiScanTool into the ELM327 type. Why do I keep getting nil?

```
import UIKit
import OBD2Kit

class ViewController: UIViewController, FLScanToolDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var hostIpAddress: UITextField!

    var scanTool: ELM327!

    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scanToolLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rpmLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var speedLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tempLabel: UILabel!
    var scanning = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.hostIpAddress.text = "192.168.0.10"
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func scanButton(sender: UIButton) {
        if !scanning {
            startScan()
        } else {
            stopScan()
        }
    }

    func startScan() {
        if let scanTool = ELM327(host: self.hostIpAddress.text!, andPort: 35000) {
            self.statusLabel.text = "Initializing..."
            scanTool.useLocation = true
            scanTool.delegate = self
            scanTool.startScanWithSensors({() -> [AnyObject] in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
                    self.statusLabel.text = "Scanning..."
                    self.scanToolLabel.text = scanTool.scanToolName
                })

//                let sensors: [AnyObject] = [    OBD2Sensor.SensorEngineRPM as! AnyObject,
//                                                OBD2Sensor.SensorVehicleSpeed as! AnyObject,
//                                                OBD2Sensor.SensorOxygenSensorsPresent as! AnyObject    ]

                let sensors: [AnyObject] = [    0x0C,
                                                0x0D,
                                                0x13    ]
                return sensors
            })
            self.scanTool = scanTool
            print("So far succesfull")
            scanning = !scanning
        } else {
            self.statusLabel.text = "Not working"
        }
    }

    func stopScan() {
        statusLabel.text = "Stopped"
        let scanTool: ELM327 = self.scanTool
        scanTool.cancelScan()
        scanTool.sensorScanTargets = nil
        scanTool.delegate = nil
        scanning = !scanning
    }

    // MARK: - FLScanToolDelegate


    func scanTool(scanTool: FLScanTool, sensor: FLECUSensor) {
        var sensorLabel: UILabel? = nil
        switch sensor.pid {

        case OBD2Sensor.SensorEngineRPM:
            sensorLabel = self.rpmLabel

        case OBD2Sensor.SensorVehicleSpeed:
            sensorLabel = self.speedLabel

        default:
            sensorLabel = self.tempLabel
        }

        self.showSensorValue(sensor, onLabel: sensorLabel!)
    }

    func showSensorValue(sensor: FLECUSensor, onLabel label: UILabel) {
        let sensorValue: String = "\(sensor.valueStringForMeasurement1(false)) \(sensor.imperialUnitString)"
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
            label.text = sensorValue
        })
    }

}
```

**Edit 1:**

I can already scan for the tool now since ELM327 is a FLWiFiScanTool and not the other way around. I can get the toolname so it's connecting but can't seem to get the sensors output.

Comment: Can `scanToolWithHost` fail?

Comment: What is `FLWifiScanTool` returning?

Comment: Please remove all the "solved" parts from your *question* and post your solution as an *answer*. Thank you.

Comment: It's okay to ask and then answer your own question, just don't do both in the Question section.

Comment: I've rolled back your question to the last "non solved" version because there was a misunderstanding. What I meant is that you should post your solution *using the "Your Answer" box*. A question should remain a question; solutions go in the answers part of the Q&A, not in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, you're right. I'll fix it. Thought it was weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. The expected sensors array should be one of NSNumbers so I casted the sensors UInt's to NSNumbers.
And I also missed the didUpdateSensor part in the scanTool function.

**Make sure to use the metric system, this is somehow way more reliable in my case. (My car is using the metric system as well, maybe that's why.)**

```
import UIKit
import OBD2Kit

class ViewController: UIViewController, FLScanToolDelegate {
    var scanTool: ELM327!

    @IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scanToolLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rpmLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var speedLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tempLabel: UILabel!
    var scanning = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func scanButton(sender: UIButton) {
        if !scanning {
            startScan()
        } else {
            stopScan()
        }
    }

    func startScan() {
        if let scanTool = ELM327(host: "192.168.0.10", andPort: 35000) {
            self.statusLabel.text = "Initializing..."
            scanTool.useLocation = true
            scanTool.delegate = self
            scanTool.startScanWithSensors({() -> [AnyObject] in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
                    self.statusLabel.text = "Scanning..."
                    self.scanToolLabel.text = scanTool.scanToolName
                })

                let sensors: [AnyObject] = [ OBD2Sensor.SensorEngineRPM as NSNumber, OBD2Sensor.SensorVehicleSpeed as NSNumber, OBD2Sensor.SensorOxygenSensorsPresent as NSNumber ]

                return sensors
            })
            self.scanTool = scanTool
            print("So far succesfull")
            scanning = !scanning
        } else {
            self.statusLabel.text = "Not working"
        }
    }

    func stopScan() {
        statusLabel.text = "Stopped"
        let scanTool: ELM327 = self.scanTool
        scanTool.cancelScan()
        scanTool.sensorScanTargets = nil
        scanTool.delegate = nil
        scanning = !scanning
    }

    // MARK: - FLScanToolDelegate

    func scanTool(scanTool: FLScanTool!, didUpdateSensor sensor: FLECUSensor!) {
        var sensorLabel: UILabel? = nil
        switch sensor.pid {

        case OBD2Sensor.SensorEngineRPM:
            sensorLabel = self.rpmLabel

        case OBD2Sensor.SensorVehicleSpeed:
            sensorLabel = self.speedLabel

        default:
            sensorLabel = self.tempLabel
        }

        self.showSensorValue(sensor, onLabel: sensorLabel!)
    }

    func showSensorValue(sensor: FLECUSensor, onLabel label: UILabel) {
        let sensorValue: String = "\(sensor.valueStringForMeasurement1(true)) \(sensor.metricUnitString)"
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() -> Void in
            label.text = sensorValue
        })
    }

}
```